# Disable automatic fan speed control of the Raspberry Pi 5 to control it manually

Tags: pwm, cooling, pi-5

I have a Raspberry Pi 5 with the official cooler/fan. [The firmware enables it from 50°C and up in different steps](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/raspberry-pi-5.html#cooling-raspberry-pi-5). I'd like to control it manually, which is possible by writing the steps to `/sys/class/thermal/cooling_device0/cur_state`:

```
echo '4' | sudo tee -a /sys/class/thermal/cooling_device0/cur_state
```

`0` disables the fan, while `1` is the first 50°C step (30% speed), `2` the second (50%) and so on. `4` is the last one, which leads to 100% fan speed. This works, but only for 1-2 seconds. It seems that the firmware is resetting my custom changes.

### What doesn't work

I tried to [disable the fan](https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?p=2162355&sid=775b61c763fc05812845712e5af9cf56#p2162355) in the `/boot/config.txt`:

```
$ grep cooling /boot/config.txt 
dtparam=cooling_fan=off
```

[Using `pinctrl`](https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?p=2165508&sid=f938d0e890ae2df897fede40652419e8#p2165508) it's possible to set some changes, which are not overwritten by the firmware:

```
# Disabling the fan
pinctrl FAN_PWM op dh
# 100% fan speed
pinctrl FAN_PWM op dl
# Letting the firmware automatically control the fan again
pinctrl FAN_PWM a0
```

This works until the next reboot. But I'm very limited, since I can only choose between 0% (fan disabled) and 100% fan speed.

### My question

How can we disable the automatic firmware, so that the 4 steps (+1 to disable) in `/sys/class/thermal/cooling_device0/cur_state` are kept longer (at least to the next reboot) instead of just for 1-2 seconds?

Comment: Have you tried combining those? Ie., disable it with pinctrl, then use the sysfs interface to set the speed.

Comment: @goldilocks Yes, it seems that `pinctrl FAN_PWM op dh` disables `/sys/class/thermal/cooling_device0/cur_state` because `echo '4' | sudo tee -a /sys/class/thermal/cooling_device0/cur_state` doesn't have any effect any more. And the file keeps `4` even after several seconds, so no firmware touch it, but it seems also not to be used.

Answer (score 1):

I also searched for a few days and didn't find what I was looking for.

So for me (with the official Raspbian) and without any modifications it actually works amazingly easy.

I use the official case with integrated fan.

I don't know if I'm allowed to post the link where I found the solution.

---

So just for your information:

*Disable the fan*
`pinctrl FAN_PWM op dh`

*100% fan speed*
`pinctrl FAN_PWM op dl`

*Let the firmware automatically control the fan again*
`pinctrl FAN_PWM a0`

---

To change the fan control, you must edit the file `/boot/firmware/config.txt`.

Information about the settings:

fan_temp0 Temperature threshold (in millicelcius) for 1st cooling level (default 50000). Pi5 only.
fan_temp0_hyst Temperature hysteresis (in millicelcius) for 1st cooling level (default 5000). Pi5 only.
fan_temp0_speed Fan PWM setting for 1st cooling level (0-255, default 75). Pi5 only.

fan_temp1 Temperature threshold (in millicelcius) for 2nd cooling level (default 60000). Pi5 only.
fan_temp1_hyst Temperature hysteresis (in millicelcius) for 2nd cooling level (default 5000). Pi5 only.
fan_temp1_speed Fan PWM setting for 2nd cooling level (0-255, default 125). Pi5 only.

fan_temp2 Temperature threshold (in millicelcius) for 3rd cooling level (default 67500). Pi5 only.
fan_temp2_hyst Temperature hysteresis (in millicelcius) for 3rd cooling level (default 5000). Pi5 only.
fan_temp2_speed Fan PWM setting for 3rd cooling level (0-255, default 175). Pi5 only.

fan_temp3 Temperature threshold (in millicelcius) for 4th cooling level (default 75000). Pi5 only.
fan_temp3_hyst Temperature hysteresis (in millicelcius) for 4th cooling level (default 5000). Pi5 only.
fan_temp3_speed Fan PWM setting for 4th cooling level (0-255, default 250). Pi5 only.

---

Simply insert the following at the end.

> dtparam=fan_temp0=47000

> dtparam=fan_temp0_hyst=6000

> dtparam=fan_temp0_speed=165

You have to set all 4 (changing the number from 0 to 1/2/3 and your speeds and timings.

Sorry, I would just like to write the text here as normal and send my config. However, this editor is completely buggy. With the above description text I could copy-paste and with my config now again not without always having everything in an extra paragraph.

Unfortunately, I cannot simply use every single line of the editor. Quite strange. But this is also my first time here. I registered to answer this question.

Comment: My setting is this:
dtparam=fan_temp0=47000

dtparam=fan_temp0_hyst=6000

dtparam=fan_temp0_speed=165



dtparam=fan_temp1=52000

dtparam=fan_temp1_hyst=6000

dtparam=fan_temp1_speed=190



dtparam=fan_temp2=57000

dtparam=fan_temp2_hyst=6000

dtparam=fan_temp2_speed=215



dtparam=fan_temp3=61000

dtparam=fan_temp3_hyst=6000

dtparam=fan_temp3_speed=255

Getting temperatures with low usage at 46°C and with 100% at 62°C

Answer (score 0):

TLDR: I created a little bash script to manually take control of the fan [here](https://gist.github.com/s-geissler/89d2dbe8ee75e67aaadf5c870cf9291e)

**Details**

You can provide fixed control by manually setting the pwm config for the respective PWM controller. To do so, you have to first unload the `pwm_fan` driver

```
$ rmmod pwm_fan
```

You can then export and activate the pwm channel and manually set the fan speed. First you have to identify the correct controller and channel. Here its `PWM1_CHAN3`.

```
$ pinctrl FAN_PWM
45: a0    pd | hi // FAN_PWM/GPIO45 = PWM1_CHAN3
```

You then export the channel for usage via sysfs

```
$ cd /sys/class/pwm/pwmchip0
$ echo 3 > export
```

You should now see `/sys/class/pwm/pwmchip0/pwm3`

```
$ ls /sys/class/pwm/pwmchip0/pwm3/
capture  duty_cycle  enable  period  polarity  power  uevent
```

Finally, you need to enable the channel and set a duty_cycle

```
$ echo 1 > enable
$ echo 10000 > duty_cycle
```

The fan should now spin at a low rate, where higher values written to `duty_cycle` mean higher RPM. The common settings 1-4 available via `echo '4' | sudo tee -a /sys/class/thermal/cooling_device0/cur_state` correspond roughly to 10000, 20000, 30000 and 40000, respectively. See the `period` below, for the maximum legal value.

**Notes**

- I am using Ubuntu Server 23.10 64bit on my Pi5. So yours may be slightly different if using another OS.
- I would assume there is an easier way to achieve this, but I haven't found it yet.
- It seems that after unloading the `pwm_fan` driver, there is no way of monitoring the actual fan speed.
- The specific numbers (e.g. number of the pwm channel, period for the pwm channel, etc. *may* be different on your device.
- A more detailed explanation of the sysfs interface for pwm can be found [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v5.10/driver-api/pwm.html#using-pwms-with-the-sysfs-interface)
- My final configuration for a non-audible fan looks like this

  ```
  $ tail -n +1 enable polarity period duty_cycle
  ==> enable <==
  1

  ==> polarity <==
  inversed

  ==> period <==
  41566

  ==> duty_cycle <==
  15000
  ```

  where `duty_cycle` and `period` are numbers in nanoseconds and `duty_cycle`  configures the fan speed, meaning the fan spins at 100% if `duty_cycle` is set to 41566. In my case, the fan starts spinning around a duty cycle of roughly 5000 (yours may be different).